# How do I stop PyCharm from showing PEP8 mix indent errors when I use triple quoted strings where indenting should be ignored

Tags: pycharm, pep8

```
VAR = '''
  indentation
here
   should
 be 
ignored because it's a string
'''
```

In actuality, PyCharm/PEP8 complains about it.

Comment: It does work for me, I pasted your code and had no complaints from PyCharm. Which version of PyCharm are you using?

Answer (score 4):

So using Pycharm 5.0 community edition I was getting this "mixed indentation" warning.. even though the indentation was not mixed.... not sure what is going on there. I didn't want to disable Pep8 checking completely since I think it's useful to help keep my code clean. You can tell Pycharm to ignore this specific error by going to Settings->Editor->Inspection selecting "Pep8 Coding Style Violation". In the bottom right you should see a "ignore errors" box, add [the Pep8 error code](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) for this error(E101) and you shouldn't see this error anymore.

Comment: That error is extremely useful in other situations though. I don't wish to disable it.